# Did Krishna interact with any foxes in Vrindavana?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, temple, adi-shankaracharya

The Sarva Siddhanta Sangraha is a work by the Advaita philosopher Adi Shankaracharya describing the views of various schools of Indian philosophy which existed in his time.  One of the schools he discusses is the Vaisheshika school, which subscribed to a philosophy of atomism. Now the Vaisheshika school believed that consciousness was only a property of the soul when it is in Samsara, and that after it has attained Moksha, it loses all consciousness and becomes like an inanimate object.  In [this excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43tBP.jpg) from the Sarva Siddanta Sangraha, Adi Shankaracharya says that if the Vaisheshika school was correct then Moksha wouldn't be very desirable:

> **I choose to be a fox in the beautiful Vrindavana** to that altogether blissless salvation of soul deliverance, which has been taught by the Vaisheshika, who, by means of the sacrifices prescribed in the Vedas and by means of the grace of the Lord, wishes to attain with great effort the (altogether feelingless) state of a swoon, a condition of existence similar to that of a stone.

I'm interested in the part in bold, about preferring to be born as a fox in Vrindavana.  My question is, did Krishna ever interact with any foxes during his time in Vrindavana?  Or is Adi Shankaracharya just extolling the glory of living in proximity to Krishna, whether one interacts with Krishna or not?

Are there any commentaries on the Sarva Siddhanta Sangraha which shed light on this?

Comment: This looks very similar to Kulashekhara Alwar's poem where he wants to be a fish, road, stone etc., in Tirumala.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma The above one doesn't praise Vrindavana but says it is better to become fox than getting Moksha, as Vaisheshikas say after Moksha one becomes inanimate like stone . Author says it's better to become fox in forest of vrinda (vrindavana) rather than becoming inanimate (getting Moksha as per Vaisheshikas)

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think it does refer to Krishna's Vrindavana.  As Sarvabhouma says, such things are a common enough idiom, for instance in the poetry of Kulasekhara Alwar.  I think Adi Shankaracharya is saying that living in the same abode as Saguna Brahman would be a preferable outcome to Moksha if Moksha really was a state of consciosnesslessness.

Comment: Well Krsna has interacted with **wolves** in a sense so maybe that's the animal interaction you're looking for.

Comment: @Surya Can you tell me if it's a mistranslation of wolf as fox?  Here is the Swarga Siddhanta Sangraha in Sanskrit: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.311086 The passage is near the end of chapter 6.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Yes It's the same text. It's mentioned in the beginning that "Shankaracharya Virachit" & further confirmed from the first chapter describing loayatas or charvakas and from rest of the chapters like Budha ,Vaisheshiki etc.

Comment: @Keshav It does say Fox and not wolf. In any case do you know why Shankaracharya refutes the Vaisheshika view within the chapter about Nyaya?

Comment: What is the Sanskrit term given for fox there?

Comment: @Triyugi The word given is Srigaala.

Comment: @Surya BTW Srigala means a jackal rather that fox according to [Monier-Williams](http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=lemma&IDWord=126594)